# Containing an Image with Div

Tags: html, css

I have a simple 3 column layout.  In the left column, there is an image that it supposed to be centered within the div, but doesn't seem to be obeying the code from the div in the style sheet.  So, colimg1.png doesn't center and doesn't seem to be situated at all in column col1.

Heres the page html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="header">
</div>
<br>
<br>

<div id="col1">
    <img src="Images/colimg1.png">
</div>

<div id="col2">
</div>

<div id="col3">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

this is the style sheet (i know there's some unused code in there but I was trying different things)

```
body {
font-family: sans-serif;
margin: 0px;
}

#header {
text-align: center;
background-color: #cccccc;
height: 75px;
}


#content {
text-align: center;
max-height: 800px;
min-width: 400px;
}

#col1{
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
}

#col2 {
   float:left;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
}

#col3 {
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
}

#navtable{
 border-width: 1px;
}

#navbar {
    min-width: 600px;
}

ul {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
display: inline;
}

a:link {
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}
a:hover{
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}
a:active{
text-decoration: none;
color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Are `img` elements being set to `display:block` somewhere else in your css? Using your exact code above, it appears that the image centers just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/51fxmvr4/

Comment: Is the image bigger than the column?

Comment: the image is I believe 235 by 185 but the columns are measured in % (33 to be exact) so most of the time the image is smaller than the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this -

```
#col1{
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
    position: relative;/*add this*/
}
#col1 img{
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

**an another method**

```css
body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 margin: 0px;
}

#header {
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #cccccc;
 height: 75px;
}


#content {
 text-align: center;
 max-height: 800px;
 min-width: 400px;
}


.wrap{
  display:table;
  width: 100%;
}

#col1 , #col2 ,#col3{
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 float: none !important;
 width: 33%;

}
#col1{
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
    
}

#col2 {
    float:left;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
}

#col3 {
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33%;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
}

#navtable{
 border-width: 1px;
}


#navbar {
    min-width: 600px;
}

ul {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
 display: inline;
}

a:link {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}
a:hover{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}
a:active{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: grey;
}
```

```html
 <div id="header">

 </div>

 <br>
 <br>
 <div class="wrap">
  <div id="col1">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQXsTRB1fecXvG0xnqJVCtAicCqxNvPgfHGr5X4G_AZIDMA7ViD">
  </div>

  <div id="col2">
  </div>

  <div id="col3">
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: your first answer made it look worse, your second method worked well.  but why didn't my original code work?